# Why WebKit font vs iOS UILabel has different Font?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am using webview & for changing font(size 50) of `WKWebKit` i am using

`let fontSetting = "<span style=\"font-size: \(fontSize)\"</span>"`

I have taken `UILabel` from storyboard of font-size 50

Why both size shows different ?

[image]
My complete code is below ---

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
    

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let htmlStr = """
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com">WebView-Button-size-50</a></p>
        """
        let fontSize = 50
        let fontSetting = "<span style=\"font-size: \(fontSize)\"</span>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(fontSetting + htmlStr, baseURL: nil)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Try giving a unit to the font-size in the style attribute. Try "pt". `let fontSetting = "<span style=\"font-size: \(fontSize)pt\"</span>"`. Or it could be a scaling issue. Setup the web view to show at 100%.

Comment: @HangarRash by using `pt` or 'px' it helped with some size, How can i solve scaling issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because UILabel took default font (means font is assigned) however for web, you didn't specify font name.

Check below code which is working fine at my end.

```
func adjustHTMLData(htmlText : String) {
    let innerFontName: String = "myFontName".localized()
    
    let innerFontSize1: CGFloat = 32*iPhoneFactorX
    let innerDirection: String = "myDir".localized()
    
    var  header002: String = htmlText
    header002 = header002.replacingOccurrences(of: "font-family", with: "f ont-family")
    header002 = header002.replacingOccurrences(of: "<font", with: "<ffont")
    
    let htmlString: String = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>body {background-color: transparent;border: 0px;margin: 10px;padding: 0px;font-family: '\(innerFontName)'; font-size: \(innerFontSize1)px;color:\(AppColors.color_000000);}</style></head><body dir='\(innerDirection)'>\(header002)<br /><br /><style>@font-face {font-family: '\(innerFontName)';font-weight: normal;src: url(\("fontTTF".localized()));}</style><style type='text/css'> iframe { width: 100%% !important; } img {width: 100% !important; height: auto;} a {text-decoration: none; color : \(AppColors.color_000000)} table {width: 100%% !important;} }</style></body></html>";
    
    print("htmlString==\(htmlString)")
    self.myWebview.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    
}
```

In localization I have

```
"fontTTF"="Poppins-Regular.ttf";
"myFontName"="Poppins-Regular";
"myDir"="LTR";
```

AppsColor have below

```
static let color_000000 : String = "#000000"
```

Comment: Thanks @Fahim Can you please add value to `innerFontName` colours etc. I don't know exact way to enter values. I am looking for default iOS font(Helvetica)